# Content Duplication and Search Engines

Tags: seo, duplicate-data

I am developing an app that allows people to publish content to my site and then pushed to their blog.  I don't want to get hit by Google or the other search engines for duplicate content, so what can I do to avoid being penalized?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to figure out which site (yours or theirs) that should be treated as the [canonical](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=139394) source of the content. Depending on your decision/answer, the following would apply:

*Your site canonical:*
 - reference the URL with the `rel="canonical"` link element.
 - delay the push to their blog by 24 hours
 - update the URL in your XML sitemap with a time-stamp
 - make all of the HREF values of any links in the article as absolute (with your domain)

*Their site canonical:*
- reference **their** site with a rel=canonical element in your head
- push instantly to their blog
- don't include any reference the article in your XML sitemap
- consider using `"noindex, follow"` in your meta
- make all of the HREF values of any links in the article as relative

Then it comes down to what control you can exert on their site - but ultimately it's up to them.